# Android view same height as width the width is dynamic

Tags: android, android-layout

Now how to tell for the `SurfaceView` to be square, have the same height as `ImageView`'s width?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlQr"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlTop">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ivScanTop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/qr_margin_top" />

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ivScanTop"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ivScanTop"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419854/7078639) answer you should extend the `SurfaceView` and add that one on the .xml file. In that case the UI designer will show a square.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your onCreate method, in Java.

1. You have to add an id to SurfaceView

You have to add this inside your SurfaceView XML declaration:

```
android:id="@+id/surfaceViewId"
```

2. In your activity java class, inside your onCreate method, try this:

Inside your onCreate method:

```
SurfaceView surface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceViewId);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivScanTop);
surface.getHolder().setFixedSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

Comment: It is not what  I wanted, but this is an acceptable

Comment: What are you looking for then, @Moni? You told in your question you were looking for a way to set SurfaceView's height the same ImageView's width. Be more specific.

Comment: well, first surface.setHeight() there isn't any method available, check it! And  Iwould like to write something in the .xml file, not the .Java

Comment: If you want to do it in xml you should use weights for your views.

Comment: Right, you must use getHolder method, to set height and width. Post edited. Let me 3 mins I will find the way to change XML file

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your views and then add this to your Activity's onCreate method :

```
ivScanTop.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        surfaceView.getHolder().setFixedSize(ivScanTop.getwidth(), ivScanTop.getwidth())  ;                       
    }
});
```